# How to access an item from a Recyclerview in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

How to access an item from a  RECYCLERVIEW ?

(I am using the following statement to access an item from listview :  listview.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.txtView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ) .

Answer (score 1):

For example consider the below class as your `ViewHolder`

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public ImageView imgProfIcon;
        public TextView tvspecies;
}
```

You can access it from `onBindViewHolder`

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.tvspecies.setText("Recycler View");
}
```

Comment: I need to access the tvspecies.setText("Recycler View");  outside onBindViewHolder().

Comment: You need access into the activity or say your requirement ?

Comment: I need to access the text view or other elements in a recycler view, anywhere from the class .I have also defined an inner class named as RecyclerView that contain the elements and functions to handle the recycler view. I want to access all the elements in a recycler view from my outer class.
Usually, in listview we use listview.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.txtView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) to access listview element from an outer class.
What has to be done for the same in RecyclerView ?

Comment: You can use callback methods for get the recycler view item  when performing any action such ie, `onClick` etc.